# Normalized sum converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_i$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $E(X_i)=0$ and $Var(X_i)=\sigma^2>0$.  Prove that the distributions of $(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i)/ (\sqrt(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2))$ converge weakly to the $N(0,1)$ distribution.

I tried using the Lyapunov central limit theorem and Lindeberg but I couldn't get anywhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By SLLN, we have
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k^2}{n}\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{E}X_1^2=\sigma^2,$$

as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Together with the classical CLT:
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k}{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\Rightarrow N(0,1)$$

gives the final result you want. You should note that a.s. convergence is stronger than convergence in distribution so we can insert the first convergence here.